# Running huey in production with Django

Tags: django, deployment

I am working on a Django project which has been deployed on a Windows server using Apache (WAMP). I have integrated Huey with the Django application to run some asynchronous tasks. I am running the consumer using the

```
python manage.py run_huey
```

command.
Is there any way to run this command as a service in the background?

Comment: Did you find a solution on this? systemd, supervisord maybe?